# How can I create an array within an array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to create UNO in python, and I've sorted all the cards into separate arrays, but to draw the cards I need to create an array containing all the arrays of different cards.

```
cards = [yellowcards = [Cards.yellow0, Cards.yellow1, Cards.yellow2, Cards.yellow3, Cards.yellow4, Cards.yellow5, Cards.yellow6,
         Cards.yellow7, Cards.yellow8, Cards.yellow9, Cards.yellowmiss, Cards.yellowreverse, Cards.yellow_2,
         Cards.yyellow1, Cards.yyellow2, Cards.yyellow3, Cards.yyellow4, Cards.yyellow5, Cards.yyellow6,
         Cards.yyellow7, Cards.yyellow8, Cards.yyellow9, Cards.yyellowmiss, Cards.yyellowreverse, Cards.yyellow_2],
         greencards = [Cards.green0, Cards.green1, Cards.green2, Cards.green3, Cards.green4, Cards.green5, Cards.green6,
         Cards.green7, Cards.green8, Cards.green9, Cards.greenmiss, Cards.greenreverse, Cards.green_2,
         Cards.ggreen1, Cards.ggreen2, Cards.ggreen3, Cards.ggreen4, Cards.ggreen5, Cards.ggreen6,
         Cards.ggreen7, Cards.ggreen8, Cards.ggreen9, Cards.ggreenmiss, Cards.ggreenreverse, Cards.ggreen_2],
         bluecards = [Cards.blue0, Cards.blue1, Cards.blue2, Cards.blue3, Cards.blue4, Cards.blue5, Cards.blue6,
         Cards.blue7, Cards.blue8, Cards.blue9, Cards.bluemiss, Cards.bluereverse, Cards.blue_2,
         Cards.bblue1, Cards.bblue2, Cards.bblue3, Cards.bblue4, Cards.bblue5, Cards.bblue6,
         Cards.bblue7, Cards.bblue8, Cards.bblue9, Cards.bbluemiss, Cards.bbluereverse, Cards.bblue_2],
         redcards = [Cards.red0, Cards.red1, Cards.red2, Cards.red3, Cards.red4, Cards.red5, Cards.red6,
         Cards.red7, Cards.red8, Cards.red9, Cards.redmiss, Cards.redreverse, Cards.red_2,
         Cards.rred1, Cards.rred2, Cards.rred3, Cards.rred4, Cards.rred5, Cards.rred6,
         Cards.rred7, Cards.rred8, Cards.rred9, Cards.rredmiss, Cards.rredreverse, Cards.rred_2],
         wildcards = [Cards.wild1, Cards.wild2, Cards.wild3, Cards.wild4, Cards.wilddraw1, Cards.wilddraw2,
         Cards.wilddraw3, Cards.wilddraw4]]
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Coldspeed These assignments are invalid syntax

Comment: the problem is that it keeps showing error messages, and no matter what i do it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @DeepSpace No I meant, if he's already figured out how to nest them, what's the problem?

Comment: This big block of code is not very readable. Have you considered assigning each of your inner arrays to separate variables first before stuffing them all into the outer array?

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could post the exact error messages you are getting from this as part of providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare your arrays inside another array like you did. You must declare them outside:

```
yellowcards = [Cards.yellow0, Cards.yellow1, Cards.yellow2, Cards.yellow3, Cards.yellow4, Cards.yellow5, Cards.yellow6,
     Cards.yellow7, Cards.yellow8, Cards.yellow9, Cards.yellowmiss, Cards.yellowreverse, Cards.yellow_2,
     Cards.yyellow1, Cards.yyellow2, Cards.yyellow3, Cards.yyellow4, Cards.yyellow5, Cards.yyellow6,
     Cards.yyellow7, Cards.yyellow8, Cards.yyellow9, Cards.yyellowmiss, Cards.yyellowreverse, Cards.yyellow_2]
greencards = [Cards.green0, Cards.green1, Cards.green2, Cards.green3, Cards.green4, Cards.green5, Cards.green6,
     Cards.green7, Cards.green8, Cards.green9, Cards.greenmiss, Cards.greenreverse, Cards.green_2,
     Cards.ggreen1, Cards.ggreen2, Cards.ggreen3, Cards.ggreen4, Cards.ggreen5, Cards.ggreen6,
     Cards.ggreen7, Cards.ggreen8, Cards.ggreen9, Cards.ggreenmiss, Cards.ggreenreverse, Cards.ggreen_2]
bluecards = [Cards.blue0, Cards.blue1, Cards.blue2, Cards.blue3, Cards.blue4, Cards.blue5, Cards.blue6,
     Cards.blue7, Cards.blue8, Cards.blue9, Cards.bluemiss, Cards.bluereverse, Cards.blue_2,
     Cards.bblue1, Cards.bblue2, Cards.bblue3, Cards.bblue4, Cards.bblue5, Cards.bblue6,
     Cards.bblue7, Cards.bblue8, Cards.bblue9, Cards.bbluemiss, Cards.bbluereverse, Cards.bblue_2]
redcards = [Cards.red0, Cards.red1, Cards.red2, Cards.red3, Cards.red4, Cards.red5, Cards.red6,
     Cards.red7, Cards.red8, Cards.red9, Cards.redmiss, Cards.redreverse, Cards.red_2,
     Cards.rred1, Cards.rred2, Cards.rred3, Cards.rred4, Cards.rred5, Cards.rred6,
     Cards.rred7, Cards.rred8, Cards.rred9, Cards.rredmiss, Cards.rredreverse, Cards.rred_2]
wildcards = [Cards.wild1, Cards.wild2, Cards.wild3, Cards.wild4, Cards.wilddraw1, Cards.wilddraw2,
     Cards.wilddraw3, Cards.wilddraw4]
cards = [yellowcards, greencards, bluecards, redcards, wildcards]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is what you are doing,

```
>>> [a=[34,34],b=[23,34]]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Assignment of this sort doesn't work.

However this works,

```
>>> a=[34,34]
>>> b=[23,34]
>>> [a,b]
[[34, 34], [23, 34]]
```

So in your case do this,

```
yellowcards = [Cards.yellow0, Cards.yellow1, Cards.yellow2, Cards.yellow3, Cards.yellow4, Cards.yellow5, Cards.yellow6,
     Cards.yellow7, Cards.yellow8, Cards.yellow9, Cards.yellowmiss, Cards.yellowreverse, Cards.yellow_2,
     Cards.yyellow1, Cards.yyellow2, Cards.yyellow3, Cards.yyellow4, Cards.yyellow5, Cards.yyellow6,
     Cards.yyellow7, Cards.yyellow8, Cards.yyellow9, Cards.yyellowmiss, Cards.yyellowreverse, Cards.yyellow_2]

greencards = [Cards.green0, Cards.green1, Cards.green2, Cards.green3, Cards.green4, Cards.green5, Cards.green6,
     Cards.green7, Cards.green8, Cards.green9, Cards.greenmiss, Cards.greenreverse, Cards.green_2,
     Cards.ggreen1, Cards.ggreen2, Cards.ggreen3, Cards.ggreen4, Cards.ggreen5, Cards.ggreen6,
     Cards.ggreen7, Cards.ggreen8, Cards.ggreen9, Cards.ggreenmiss, Cards.ggreenreverse, Cards.ggreen_2]

bluecards = [Cards.blue0, Cards.blue1, Cards.blue2, Cards.blue3, Cards.blue4, Cards.blue5, Cards.blue6,
     Cards.blue7, Cards.blue8, Cards.blue9, Cards.bluemiss, Cards.bluereverse, Cards.blue_2,
     Cards.bblue1, Cards.bblue2, Cards.bblue3, Cards.bblue4, Cards.bblue5, Cards.bblue6,
     Cards.bblue7, Cards.bblue8, Cards.bblue9, Cards.bbluemiss, Cards.bbluereverse, Cards.bblue_2]

redcards = [Cards.red0, Cards.red1, Cards.red2, Cards.red3, Cards.red4, Cards.red5, Cards.red6,
     Cards.red7, Cards.red8, Cards.red9, Cards.redmiss, Cards.redreverse, Cards.red_2,
     Cards.rred1, Cards.rred2, Cards.rred3, Cards.rred4, Cards.rred5, Cards.rred6,
     Cards.rred7, Cards.rred8, Cards.rred9, Cards.rredmiss, Cards.rredreverse, Cards.rred_2]

wildcards = [Cards.wild1, Cards.wild2, Cards.wild3, Cards.wild4, Cards.wilddraw1, Cards.wilddraw2,
     Cards.wilddraw3, Cards.wilddraw4]

cards = [yellowcards,greencards,bluecards, redcards, wildcards]
```

However as other users suggested. Try using the `dictionary` instead having a list of list.

Also on a **Side note:**

The general definition for *Arrays* is:

> In programming, a series of objects all of which are the same size and type. Each object in an array is called an array element.

However in python you have `lists` instead. These lists can have different datatype of different types. Like

```
a_list = [1,2,3] #all int
b = ['s','a','d'] #all strings [Note there is no char here just str type with length 1
c = [1,2,3,'a','s',a_list] #mixed list
```

All are valid. Do remember this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
cards = {"yellowcards" : [Cards.yellow0, Cards.yellow1, Cards.yellow2, Cards.yellow3, Cards.yellow4, Cards.yellow5, Cards.yellow6,
         Cards.yellow7, Cards.yellow8, Cards.yellow9, Cards.yellowmiss, Cards.yellowreverse, Cards.yellow_2,
         Cards.yyellow1, Cards.yyellow2, Cards.yyellow3, Cards.yyellow4, Cards.yyellow5, Cards.yyellow6,
         Cards.yyellow7, Cards.yyellow8, Cards.yyellow9, Cards.yyellowmiss, Cards.yyellowreverse, Cards.yyellow_2],
         "greencards" : [Cards.green0, Cards.green1, Cards.green2, Cards.green3, Cards.green4, Cards.green5, Cards.green6,
         Cards.green7, Cards.green8, Cards.green9, Cards.greenmiss, Cards.greenreverse, Cards.green_2,
         Cards.ggreen1, Cards.ggreen2, Cards.ggreen3, Cards.ggreen4, Cards.ggreen5, Cards.ggreen6,
         Cards.ggreen7, Cards.ggreen8, Cards.ggreen9, Cards.ggreenmiss, Cards.ggreenreverse, Cards.ggreen_2],
         "bluecards" : [Cards.blue0, Cards.blue1, Cards.blue2, Cards.blue3, Cards.blue4, Cards.blue5, Cards.blue6,
         Cards.blue7, Cards.blue8, Cards.blue9, Cards.bluemiss, Cards.bluereverse, Cards.blue_2,
         Cards.bblue1, Cards.bblue2, Cards.bblue3, Cards.bblue4, Cards.bblue5, Cards.bblue6,
         Cards.bblue7, Cards.bblue8, Cards.bblue9, Cards.bbluemiss, Cards.bbluereverse, Cards.bblue_2],
         "redcards" : [Cards.red0, Cards.red1, Cards.red2, Cards.red3, Cards.red4, Cards.red5, Cards.red6,
         Cards.red7, Cards.red8, Cards.red9, Cards.redmiss, Cards.redreverse, Cards.red_2,
         Cards.rred1, Cards.rred2, Cards.rred3, Cards.rred4, Cards.rred5, Cards.rred6,
         Cards.rred7, Cards.rred8, Cards.rred9, Cards.rredmiss, Cards.rredreverse, Cards.rred_2],
         "wildcards" : [Cards.wild1, Cards.wild2, Cards.wild3, Cards.wild4, Cards.wilddraw1, Cards.wilddraw2,
         Cards.wilddraw3, Cards.wilddraw4]}
```

So you can access each one of the color like this.

```
cars["yellowcards"]
```

output

```
[Cards.yellow0, Cards.yellow1, Cards.yellow2, Cards.yellow3, Cards.yellow4, Cards.yellow5, Cards.yellow6,
         Cards.yellow7, Cards.yellow8, Cards.yellow9, Cards.yellowmiss, Cards.yellowreverse, Cards.yellow_2,
         Cards.yyellow1, Cards.yyellow2, Cards.yyellow3, Cards.yyellow4, Cards.yyellow5, Cards.yyellow6,
         Cards.yyellow7, Cards.yyellow8, Cards.yyellow9, Cards.yyellowmiss, Cards.yyellowreverse, Cards.yyellow_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

So from your question I figure you already have these lists:

```
yellowcards = [Cards.yellow0, Cards.yellow1, Cards.yellow2, Cards.yellow3, Cards.yellow4, Cards.yellow5, Cards.yellow6, Cards.yellow7, Cards.yellow8, Cards.yellow9, Cards.yellowmiss, Cards.yellowreverse, Cards.yellow_2, Cards.yyellow1, Cards.yyellow2, Cards.yyellow3, Cards.yyellow4, Cards.yyellow5, Cards.yyellow6, Cards.yyellow7, Cards.yyellow8, Cards.yyellow9, Cards.yyellowmiss, Cards.yyellowreverse, Cards.yyellow_2],

greencards = [Cards.green0, Cards.green1, Cards.green2, Cards.green3, Cards.green4, Cards.green5, Cards.green6, Cards.green7, Cards.green8, Cards.green9, Cards.greenmiss, Cards.greenreverse, Cards.green_2, Cards.ggreen1, Cards.ggreen2, Cards.ggreen3, Cards.ggreen4, Cards.ggreen5, Cards.ggreen6, Cards.ggreen7, Cards.ggreen8, Cards.ggreen9, Cards.ggreenmiss, Cards.ggreenreverse, Cards.ggreen_2]

bluecards = [Cards.blue0, Cards.blue1, Cards.blue2, Cards.blue3,Cards.blue4, Cards.blue5, Cards.blue6, Cards.blue7, Cards.blue8, Cards.blue9, Cards.bluemiss, Cards.bluereverse, Cards.blue_2, Cards.bblue1, Cards.bblue2, Cards.bblue3, Cards.bblue4, Cards.bblue5, Cards.bblue6, Cards.bblue7, Cards.bblue8, Cards.bblue9, Cards.bbluemiss, Cards.bbluereverse, Cards.bblue_2]

redcards = [Cards.red0, Cards.red1, Cards.red2, Cards.red3, Cards.red4, Cards.red5, Cards.red6, Cards.red7, Cards.red8, Cards.red9, Cards.redmiss, Cards.redreverse, Cards.red_2, Cards.rred1, Cards.rred2, Cards.rred3, Cards.rred4, Cards.rred5, Cards.rred6, Cards.rred7, Cards.rred8, Cards.rred9, Cards.rredmiss, Cards.rredreverse, Cards.rred_2]

wildcards = [Cards.wild1, Cards.wild2, Cards.wild3, Cards.wild4, Cards.wilddraw1, Cards.wilddraw2, Cards.wilddraw3, Cards.wilddraw4]
```

If you are trying to create a list of lists, do so:

```
cards = [yellowcards, greencards, bluecards, redcards, wildcards]
```

This will yield a list containing 5 elements, which are your original lists. You would access the green two with `cards[1][2]` - the second element of `cards` is the list with all green cards, and the third element of that list is the green two.

However, your original approach looks more than a `dict`:

```
cards = {"yellowcards" : yellowcards,
         "greencards" : greencards,
         "bluecards" : bluecards,
         "redcards" : redcards,
         "wildcards" : wildcards}
```

That way you can access the green two with `cards["greencards"][2]`.